# Не могу достучаться к названию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Доброе время суток, форумчане. Есть html в нем несколько форм, на каждой форме кнопка («`name`» и «`id`», кнопок одинаковое на каждой форме).

**Html:**

```
<form name="forma5">
    <button name="but5" id="but5" onclick="out_text()">Call out_text</button>
</form>
```

**Js:**

```
function out_text()
{
    var a = document.forma5.but5.value;
    alert('name button ("forma5") ='+a);
}
```

Почему-то в таком виде у меня в js не получается получить «`value`»?  Вариант в js: «`a = document.getElementById('but5').value`» - работает, но он конечно же не подходит.

Заранее **спасибо**!

Comment: @Konstantin78

   document.getElementById('but5').value

Вы уверены, что это работает?

Comment: извиняюсь - ошибся - не работает.
работает:
html:
 <input type="button" id="but5" onClick = "out_text8()" value="Call out_text (form 5)">
js:
var a = document.forma5.but5.value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var el = document.forma5.but5;

console.log(el.innerText || el.textContent);
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/6umved35/3/)

Comment: спасибо все получилось,
только я не понял, зачем:

    //if html
     alert(a.innerHTML || a.outerHTML);

Comment: Что касается

     el.innerText || el.textContent

, то `el.innerText` для IE < 9

   a.innerHTML || a.outerHTML

А здесь я погорячился. `outerHTML` возвращает текущую ноду целиком. Опять же, для IE существуют свои особенности по вставки html через `innerHTML`. 

Особенность браузеров (с большим перекос в сторону IE < 9), является одной из причин почему используются библиотеки, такие, как JQuery.

> А можно, чтоб после отработки скрипта, не перезагружалась страничка?

Для этоко в обработчике на клик, необходимо [указать `event.preventDefault()`](http://goo.gl/THMqbm).

Comment:  еще раз спасибо